# Getting the list of friends online API

Tags: javascript, php

I am working for a project here, i have a question, by any chance is it possible to get the list of friends online using face_book API?. please help me.. thanks.

Comment: here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/

Comment: show us what you had tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
GET /v2.8/{user-id}/friends HTTP/1.1 
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

Comment: Thank you for your effort sir, but it is just getting the number of total friends. I am asking for the list of friends online :) ..